# Compiling CUDA Library: Works on Mac, not on Ubuntu

Tags: c, macos, ubuntu, cuda, makefile

I'm making my first attempts at building a `.so` full of CUDA routines. I have `matrix_vector_mult.cu` file which currently does nothing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
double *
matrix_vector_mult(const double ** const M,
                   const double * const v,
                   const size_t num_rows,
                   const size_t num_cols)
{
    printf("Hello!\n");
    double * p = (double *) malloc(num_rows*sizeof(double));
    return p;
}
```

I also have a makefile, whose contents is as follows:

```
CC := clang
UNAME := $(shell uname -s)
ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
CUDA_PATH := /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-6.5
CUDA_LIB := ${CUDA_PATH}/lib
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
CUDA_PATH := /usr/local/cuda-6.5
CUDA_LIB := ${CUDA_PATH}/lib64
endif
LIBS := -L ${CUDA_LIB} -lcudart -lcudadevrt
NVCC := ${CUDA_PATH}/bin/nvcc -ccbin ${CC}
CFLAGS := -g -std=c11 -Wextra -Wall -I include -rpath ${CUDA_LIB}
NVCCFLAGS := -g -m64 -D__STRICT_ANSI__

vpath %.cu src
vpath %.h include

all: matrix_vector_mult.o
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o matrix_vector_mult.so -shared -fPIC $^ ${LIBS}

matrix_vector_mult.o: matrix_vector_mult.cu
        ${NVCC} ${NVCCFLAGS} -o $@ -c $^

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.so *.pyc
```

On Mac, this compiles just fine. However, on my Ubuntu box, I get the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: matrix_vector_mult.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
matrix_vector_mult.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

What could be the problem? (Adding `-fPIC` to the compile line doesn't work.) `nvcc --version` yields identical information on both boxes, `clang --version` gives

```
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
```

on the Mac, and

```
Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
```

on the Ubuntu box. I somewhat doubt the slight LLVM version difference is the problem, because I regard the makefile as a mess already. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Like the error says, you need to pass `-fPIC` to compile to position independent code on ELF platforms. How did you add it to the compile statements (and are you familiar with the nvcc `-Xcompiler` directive?)

Comment: I tried the `-fPIC`, but I've never seen the `-Xcompiler` switch; that solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Building a shared library of host object usually requires compiling those objects so that they contain only position independent code. As the error message indicates, you do that using the `-fPIC` host compiler option on a gnu-linux system using gcc.

nvcc includes an option `-XCompiler`, which can be used to pass options to the host compiler. So adding `-XCompiler="-fPIC"` to the compilation statements used to generate the host code used to build to shared library can be used to solve this particular problem.